# Active Directory GPO for 'referer' HTTP Header

Tags: active-directory, gpo

Do any of the Active Directory GPOs prevent 'referer' HTTP headers from being sent during web browsing? i.e. for a workstation joined to Active Directory.

Answer (score 0):

GPOs can do almost anything. Execute the following command to generate a HTML report showing what group policy settings are applied to your user and computer:

```
gpresult /h report.html
```